# Update JFrame window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel, updates

I'm doing a simple java application that essentially shows a certain amount of letters (ABCDE etc) from an array, each one displayer in a portion of a grid. There are two buttons, one that will shift the letters to the left (so that one shift will become BCDEA and the right shift will go EABCD).

I've got the shifting and everything else working, as I've tested using a System output. But how do I get the window to refresh and show me the updated JLabels? They stay the same (ABCDE) after I shift them.

I've tried revalidate() and repaint() both inside the buttons' ActionListeners and on the shift method that they call, but nothing happens. Any tips on this?

Comment: I am hoping I won't need to do a for cycle under both actionlisteners where each label will have to be updated manually and added again to the grid

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be more helpful

Answer (score 2):

> I've tried revalidate() and repaint()

You only use those methods when you create a new component and add the component to a visible GUI. So it sounds like you are trying to remove/add the labels in the new order you want the labels to be displayed.

Maybe an easier approach is to leave the label in the same order but just change the text on each label. Then all you need to do is

```
label.setText();
```

and the label will repaint itself automatically without you invoking revalidate() and repaint().